# How to properly use std::getline function

Tags: c++, getline

I have a file that includes the name of someone, what course they where in, and the roster

ex. John.Smith:11:F12

Currently the output is this

```
George.Clooney

Jennifer.Lawrence

Kevin.Bacon


15:S13

15:F15

15:F15
```

How would I get rid of the colons for the course reference? I want it to look like this

`15S13`

My code

```
struct studentinfo
{
     string name;
     string classref;
};

void readNumbers(istream &input, char *argv[], int argc)
{

    string program = argv[0];
    string text = argv[1];
    studentinfo array[10];
    string name;
    int i=0;

    if(text=="students.txt"){   
        while(!getline(input, array[i].name, ':').eof()){
            input >> array[i].classref; 
            i++;
   }

    for(int j=0; j < i; j++){ 
        cout<< array[j].name << endl;
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){ 
        cout << array[i].classref << endl;
    }       
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the usage pattern, no? How often do you do queries relative to updates, which sort of queries you do, etc. As an extreme example, if you almost never query, and only update, you might use a vector to which you append stuff at the end.

Comment: Really, depends on what do you want to store it for - are you asking about persistence or internal storage? Is your project big? Will you update it more often than query? Do you have some natural keys?

Comment: @Lauren You should ask new questions rather than edit an existing one to completely change what its asking. You've now made my answer completely out of context. You will get a better rating by asking more questions, so it's in your interest to do it too.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the answer to several iterations of this question, so it may seem a little out of whack with what is being asked above.**

---

The problem is that you are using `std::getline` to read up to the ':' character. You then use the overloaded operator `>>` for `std::string`, to do another read into the same string `name` overwriting it. This time it reads to the end of the line.

After the call to `std::getline` the variable `name` contains `John.Smith` and then you immediately overwrite that value by executing `input >> name;`. Which is essentially the same thing as `getline`, without the ability to specify a delimiter. The string `name` then contains `11:F12`, which you copy to your array to later display.

I think your confusion with how `getline` works was seen here, you didn't need to read the name value using `>>` it was already in the string `name`. You just needed to read the rest of the line and discard it. I recommend you read an online reference for [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to better grasp how it works.

To fix your issue you could do any of the following.

1. Do another 'getline' or '>>' after you have copied `name` to the array and discard the value, that way it clears out the rest of the line and you then read the next name in your looped `getline` call. A slightly hacky way of achieving this is to move `input >> name;` after the line which adds `name` to the array.
2. Read the whole line, without delimiter and then find (using `find` member function) the first occurrence of ':' and take a substring up to that character (using `substr` member function).
3. Define a struct with name & class members and read both values into the struct. This way you deliberately read both values from the file. If you don't care about the course string this might be overkill.

Some code that more or less does what I'm suggesting.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void readNumbers(istream &input)
 {
    string array[10];
    string name;
    string garbage;
    int i=0;

    while(getline(input, name, ':'))
    {           
        array[i]=name;
        i++;

        input >> garbage;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) cout<< array[i] << '\n';
 }

 void readNumbers2(istream &input)
 {
    string array[10];
    string ln;
    int i=0;

    while(getline(input, ln))
    {           
        size_t colpos = ln.find(':'); 

        if(colpos != string::npos)
        {
            array[i]=ln.substr(0, colpos);
            i++;
        }            
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) cout<< array[i] << '\n';
 }

 struct studentinfo
 {
     string name;
     string classref;
 };

 void readNumbers3(istream &input)
 {
    studentinfo array[10];
    string name;
    int i=0;

    while(getline(input, array[i].name, ':'))
    {
        input >> array[i].classref;
        i++;
    }

    for(int j=0; j < i; j++) 
        cout<< "name=" << array[j].name << '\n';
 }

int main()
{
    std::ifstream f("students.txt");

    readNumbers(f);
}
```

Of course this doe not deal with edge cases, such as empty lines in your file or overrunning the array, but it demonstrates use of `std::getline`. I'd also suggest you look at `std::vector` or `std::array` to hold your strings and use iterators or the range based for loop to print the values.

To remove the colon from your string you can use the following method. use `find` to find the colon characters index and the single iterator overload of [`string::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) to remove the character at that position.

```
void charerase()
{
    std::string s("15:F15");

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    size_t cpos = s.find(':');

    if(cpos != std::string::npos)
    {
        s.erase(s.begin() + cpos);
    }

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

For this you will need to include the header `<iterator>`.